# How can I cut videos with otrverwaltung when avidemux crashes?

Tags: software-recommendation, video, avidemux

I use `otrverwaltung` (Version 0.9.1) to decode and cut videos from "Online TV Recorder". `otrverwaltung` starts `avidemux` (Version: 1:2.5.4-0ubuntu13), but this instantly crashes.

([Here](http://pastebin.com/P9C0Sb8a) is what gets printed in the console. It seems to be related to [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/avidemux/+bug/404585).)

What can I do to cut the videos? Is there other software that can do this?

Answer (score 0):

## [LiVES](http://lives.sourceforge.net/)

> For the more technically minded, the application is frame and sample
> accurate, and it can be controlled remotely or scripted for use as a
> video server. And it supports all of the latest free standards.

Available at the Software Centre.

## [OpenShot](http://openshot.org)

> OpenShot Video Editor is a free, open-source video editor for Linux
> licensed under the GPL version 3.0.
>
> OpenShot can take your videos, photos, and music files and help you
> create the film you have always dreamed of. Easily add sub-titles,
> transitions, and effects, and then export your film to DVD, YouTube,
> Vimeo, Xbox 360, and many other common formats.

Also available from the Software Centre.

## [Pitivi](http://www.pitivi.org/)

> PiTiVi allows users to easily edit audio/video projects based on the
> GStreamer framework.  PiTIVi provides several ways of creating and
> modifying a timeline.  Ranging from a simple synopsis view (a-la
> iMovie) to the full-blown editing view (aka Complex View) which puts
> you in complete control of your editing.

Also available from the Software Centre.